# Can one develop non-nested azure arm firewallrules?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

This is to find out if something I'm attempting is even possible...

I've seen several examples of developing an entry ARM template (`azuredeploy.json`) that refs/imports an external child resource template (eg: `azuredeploy.sql.server.json`) within which is defined a new SQL Server as well as  -- within the sql server's `resources` section -- nested resources, such as a firewallrule.

I've seen one example (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2017/01/11/arm-template-to-deploy-server-with-auditing-and-threat-detection-turned-on/) where the entry/parent ARM template (eg: `azuredeploy.json`) defines the SQL Server, and instead of defining the firewall rules as a nested resources, defines the firewall rules in parallel, using `dependsOn` to define execution order.

That appears to be a bit more maintainable/less nested than the first approach.

But I'd like to push it further, where the above resources are all defined in external templates: `azuredeploy.json` invoking `azuredeploy.sql.server.json` *and* `azuredeploy.sql.server.firewallRules.json`

Unfortunately, I've not found a single example of the above approach.

I've tried for most of the afternoon -- but having changed slashes of ids and names to every configuration imaginable, have run over and over again into:

Code=InvalidTemplate
Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource {resource-name}' 
for type {resource-type} has incorrect segment lengths.

So the questions are:
a) any reason it should not be done this way? (I felt it allowed for a more modular set of arm templates, that could be referenced from a flat entry arm file, only requiring a correct set of 'dependsOn' attributes being defined)
b) can the above actually be done?!
c) is there an online example to study of the above approach and understand my approach error?
d) Just in case: when it's giving the error messages regarding the segment lengths...any chance it's getting itself confused, and it's taking into account "Microsoft.Resources/deployments", when it should be taking into account only "Microsoft.Sql/servers" and "Microsoft.Sql/servers/firewallRules"?

Much appreciated if anybody can advance me on this sticking point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do this, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/servers/firewallrules

The error you posted suggests that you're missing a name segment or type segment - those must match as in the example below.

```
        "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/firewallrules",
        "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('serverName'), '/', 'AllowAllWindowsAzureIps')]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "properties": {
            "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
            "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
        }
```

So your name property will be something like

sqlServerResourceName/whateverYouWantToNameTheFirewallRules - and type exactly as in the example above.

Comment: Thanks. <<The error you posted suggests that you're missing a name segment or type segment>> that led to me looking more closely at how I was referencing between the two, and I got there in the end. Thanks.